# ending String, recursive, and searching for occurances

Tags: java, string, recursion

What my codes does is pass two string and a count in the method countSubstring.
countSubString count the occurances of strTwo in strOne. 
But I am have difficulty because I don't understand a few things:

```
    public class CountingSubString
    {
        int CountSubString(String strOne, String strTwo, int count)
        {
          int i = 0;
          int foundAtIndex = strOne.indexOf(strTwo, i);
           if(foundAtIndex == -1)
        {
            i++;
        }
         else//(foundAtIndex != -1)
        {
         count++;
          int newStartIndex = foundAtIndex + strTwo.length();
         String StringFromString = strOne.substring(newStartIndex, strOne.length()-1);
          count = count + countSubString(StringFromString, strTwo, count);
         return count;
        }
         return count;
       }
         public class TestCountingSubString 
      {
           public static void main(String[] argv)
         {
           String s2 = new String("abab");
            String s3 = new String("ab");
          String s4 = new String("aabbaa");
          String s5 = new String("aa");
          countingSubString CountOfString = new countingSubString();
          int count = CountOfString.countSubString(s2, s3, 0);
         System.out.println(count);
          }
      }
```

Question 1) let consider a case where string1 = c, and string2 = aa.
aa is not contained in c. 
 How do I make a base case for this case?
My attempt:

Question 2) In java how does a string end?
If I have string1 = "aabbaa", and string2 = "aa".
I get aa from index 0 and 1, so I return index 0. compute string2.length() + 0 = 2.
Now I substring string 1 at beginIndex: 2 to endindex: string2.length-1 to get new string to obtain "bbaa".
Searching again, I obtain string aa at index 2 and 3.
How do I make my recursive end after the string aa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you complicating things. It's java, use its features.

```
String string1 = "abab";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string1);
int count = 0;
while (m.find()){
    count +=1;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Also for your understanding, substring function has following format

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

where

```
beginIndex -- the begin index, inclusive.

endIndex -- the end index, exclusive.
```

Safety condition as asked in Question 1

```
if (strOne == null || strOne.equals("") || strTwo.length() < sub.length())
 return 0;
```

Solution to Question 2

```
int index =  strOne.indexOf(strTwo);
if(index!=-1){
    count++;
    count+= countSubString(strOne.substring(index+1),strTwo,0);
}
```

So complete solution is

```
class countingSubString
 {
    int countSubString(String strOne, String strTwo, int count)
    {
      if (strOne == null || strOne.equals("") || strOne.length() < strTwo.length())
        return 0;

      int index =  strOne.indexOf(strTwo);
      if(index!=-1){
        count++;
        count+= countSubString(strOne.substring(index+1),strTwo,0);
      }

      return count;
   }
}
```

Also `remove public modifier from class countingSubString` as there can be only one public class in one file. And also follow naming convention so class name should be

```
CountingSubString instead of countingSubString
```

Comment: That beats the answer I was about to give... :)

Comment: Since I am reading a book Programming in Java by dianel liang chaper 20 about recursion, I got to do it with recursive calling but this answer make things easier

Comment: @DavidHang See if this solution works for you. if yes, accept answer otherwise comment.

Comment: Okay,  use an or statement on null, empty and check lenght. Question 1 has been answered!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function as follows. I modified the class and function names a little bit.

You don't need to pass 'count' parameter to countSub function, since it will be eventually returned recursively.

```
public class Count 
{
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String s2 = new String("ababab");
    String s3 = new String("ab");

    String s4 = new String("aabbaa");
    String s5 = new String("aa");


    int count = countSub(s2, s3);
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  public static int countSub(String strOne, String strTwo) {

    int foundAtIndex = strOne.indexOf(strTwo);

    if(foundAtIndex == -1) {
      return 0;

    } else {
      int newStartIndex = foundAtIndex + strTwo.length();
      String newString = strOne.substring(newStartIndex, strOne.length());

      return (1 + countSub(newString, strTwo));
    }
  }
}
```